# Java 8 Security blocking the applet stored on my computer

Tags: java, html, security, applet

I've made a simple java applet that literally only draws "Hello World". I've searched the internet for hours but nobody seems to know how to allow locally stored applets to run when Java 8 is installed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As an after thought this is my html file I'm trying to open in Internet Explorer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>My Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World Applet</h1>
    <applet code="Main.class" width=150 height=25></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

with Main.class being my compiled applet file.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: No there's no teacher. I just didn't realize that applets weren't big anymore haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AppletViewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) for testing and development. To run in a web-browser you will need to create a [signed jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html) (because of security restrictions). From the linked Understanding Signing and Verification, *Once you (or your browser) have verified that an applet is from a trusted source, you can have the platform relax security restrictions to let the applet perform operations that would ordinarily be forbidden. A trusted applet can have freedoms as specified by the policy file in force.*